# Access project variable value through Gitlab API

Tags: bash, api, gitlab, gitlab-api

I was able to get the list printed out as in [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/api/project_level_variables.html). However I am unable to print only the value of the variable. I am using Bash and I am very new to it, so apologies, if this is stupid question.
My desired output is only the value of variable specified by its key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example provided:

```
curl .... | jq '.[] | select(.key=="TEST_VARIABLE_1").value'
```

Run the curl command and pipe through jq. Select entries where key is equal to TEST_VARIABLE_1 and print only the value entry.